# unrecognized selector sent to instance even though the selector is defined

Tags: objective-c, swift3

I have a protocol defined as follows

```
@protocol BaseCell 
 -(void) configureCellData:(id)data index:(NSIndexPath*)indexPath
@end
```

Then in swift I am doing the following:

```
@objc(MyCell)
class MyCell: UICollectionViewCell , BaseCell {
    public func configureCellData(_ data: Any!, index: IndexPath!) {

    }
}
```

Yet when I run the class, it gives me unrecognized selector for instance

Edit:
The crash

```
    NSInvalidArgumentException -[UICollectionViewCell configureCellData:index:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fa09be01200
userInfo:(null)
call stack:(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000106e5534b __exceptionPreprocess + 171
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x000000010bbef21e objc_exception_throw + 48
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000106ec4f34 -[NSObject(NSObject) doesNotRecognizeSelector:] + 132
    3   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000106ddac15 ___forwarding___ + 1013
    4   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000106dda798 _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 120
```

Comment: Try `AnyObject` instead of `Any`.

Comment: @Avi I tried, in this case the project doesnt compile for failing to conform to said protocol

Comment: What is the precise selector reported in the runtime error?

Comment: @Avi please see edited question

Comment: You didn't create an instance of `MyCell`.

Comment: @Avi the instance is created in cellForRowAt:tIndexPath

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/125276/discussion-between-avi-and-lena-bru).